# Creating Multiple DataFrames with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, pandas-datareader

Is there a way to use a 'for loop' or something similar to run through the code to create multiple DataFrames with Pandas that I can assign to separate variables, instead of hardcoding both DataFrames?

If I add new tickers it wouldn't be efficient to keep hardcoding them.

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from datetime import datetime

Equity_Tickers = ["FB", "MSFT"]

start = datetime(2018, 9, 15)
end = datetime.today().date()

# First DataFrame 
data = pdr.DataReader(Equity_Tickers[0], 'yahoo', start, end)
df = data[['Adj Close']]

# Second DataFrame
data = pdr.DataReader(Equity_Tickers[1], 'yahoo', start, end)
df1 = data[['Adj Close']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly use a variable instead of hard-coding the ticker:

```
ticker = Equity_Tickers[0]  # FB
data = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
```

To create a loop, you could do something like:

```
for ticker in Equity_Tickers:
    data = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
    df = data[['Adj Close']]
```

The tricky thing is storing the `df` variable in each iteration of the loop instead of overwriting it. One solution is to store each DataFrame in a list or dictionary.

```
frames = []
for ticker in Equity_Tickers:
    data = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
    frames.append(data[['Adj Close']])

# eg, use frames[0] to access first ticker's DataFrame
```

OR

```
frames = {}
for ticker in Equity_Tickers:
    data = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
    frames[ticker] = data[['Adj Close']]

# eg, use frames['FB'] to access FB ticker's DataFrame
```

If you're feeling really fancy you could also use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) / dictionary comprehension to accomplish this in one line:

```
# list comprehension
frames = [pdr.DataReader(t, 'yahoo', start, end)[['Adj Close']] for t in Equity_Tickers]

# dict comprehension
frames = {t: pdr.DataReader(t, 'yahoo', start, end)[['Adj Close']] for t in Equity_Tickers}
```

**Additional note:** You might also consider combining the frames into one large DataFrame, perhaps a [tidy-style DataFrame](http://www.jeannicholashould.com/tidy-data-in-python.html) where "ticker" is a field for each row.